# Wordpress wp_schedule_event does not fire

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to send out emails once every day. I copied the functions below, they are working just fine when I fire it manually but when I try to set up a wp_schedrule_event it never gets fired. Tried to get it to work with /wp-cron.php? but had no effect. I am not so good at either wp or PHP, so i might be messing up some basic stuff. I did try nearly all the suggestions I could find here or anywhere else on google, but so far non of them worked for me.

```
function get_expiring_jobs($days_notice) {
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = WP_JOB_BOARD_PRO_JOB_LISTING_PREFIX;

    $notice_before_ts = current_time( 'timestamp' ) + ( DAY_IN_SECONDS * $days_notice );
    $job_ids          = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
        "
        SELECT postmeta.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} as postmeta
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as posts ON postmeta.post_id = posts.ID
        WHERE postmeta.meta_key = %s
        AND postmeta.meta_value = %s
        AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND posts.post_type = 'job_listing'
        ",
        $prefix.'expiry_date',
        date( 'Y-m-d', $notice_before_ts )
    ) );

    return $job_ids;
}   
function send_employer_expiring_notice_manual() {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( !wp_job_board_pro_get_option('employer_notice_expiring_listing') ) {
        return;
    }
    $days_notice = wp_job_board_pro_get_option('employer_notice_expiring_listing_days');
        $job_ids = get_expiring_jobs($days_notice);
        if ( $job_ids ) {
        foreach ( $job_ids as $job_id ) {
            // send email here.
            $job = get_post($job_id);
            $email_from = get_option( 'admin_email', false );
            $headers = sprintf( "From: %s <%s>\r\n Content-type: text/html", get_bloginfo('name'), $email_from );
            $author_id = WP_Job_Board_Pro_Job_Listing::get_author_id($job->ID);
                if ( WP_Job_Board_Pro_User::is_employer($author_id) ) {
                $employer_id = WP_Job_Board_Pro_User::get_employer_by_user_id($author_id);
                $email_to = WP_Job_Board_Pro_Employer::get_post_meta($employer_id, 'email');
            }
            if ( empty($email_to) ) {
                $email_to = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author_id );
            }
            
            $subject = WP_Job_Board_Pro_Email::render_email_vars(array('job' => $job), 'employer_notice_expiring_listing', 'subject');
            $content = WP_Job_Board_Pro_Email::render_email_vars(array('job' => $job), 'employer_notice_expiring_listing', 'content');
            
            WP_Job_Board_Pro_Email::wp_mail( $email_to, $subject, $content, $headers );
                
        }
    }
}
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){
    if(!isset($schedules["5min"])){
        $schedules["5min"] = array(
            'interval' => 5*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes'));
    }
    if(!isset($schedules["30min"])){
        $schedules["30min"] = array(
            'interval' => 30*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 30 minutes'));
    }
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');

function send_out_daily_mail() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'send_mail_listing_expires' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'send_mail_listing_expires' );
    }
}
add_action('send_mail_listing_expires','send_employer_expiring_notice_manual' );
```

Comment: Install wp cron plugin to check your events. In send_out_daily_mail add error_log('Event is running'); and check your debug.log ( https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ ) is it working or not.

Comment: Thank you! I could sort it out with the use of the plugin.